# How to use custom drawing in QGraphicsViews in PyQt?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I need to view `QGraphicsScene` in 2 `QGraphicsViews` with condition that they have different scale factors for items in scene. Closest function which I found is `drawItems()`, but as far I can understand, it must be called manually. How to repaint views automatically?
I have these two code fragments in program:

```
class TGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        print("__init__")
        QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent)

    def drawItems(self, Painter, ItemCount, Items, StyleOptions):
        print("drawItems")
        Brush = QBrush(Qt.red, Qt.SolidPattern)
        Painter.setBrush(Brush)
        Painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, 100, 100)
```

## ...

```
    Mw.gvNavigation = TGraphicsView(Mw) # Mw - main window
    Mw.gvNavigation.setGeometry(0, 0, Size1, Size1)
    Mw.gvNavigation.setScene(Mw.Scene)
    Mw.gvNavigation.setSceneRect(0, 0, Size2, Size2)
    Mw.gvNavigation.show()
```

`__init__` works, `Mw.gvNavigation` is displayed and there are `Mw.Scene items` in it, but `drawItems()` isn't called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawItems methods on QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene objects have been deprecated in Qt 4.6 and have to be enabled using the IndirectPainting flag, but I would't recommend using deprecated features.

Here's another [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431568/multiple-qgraphicsviews-with-one-qgraphicsscene) on a similar issue. One of the answers shows how to make the paint methods on individual items in a scene aware of which view is painting them, and use different paint code when drawn in different views.